# Mail server problem

Tags: fedora, sendmail

I have a mail server on linux fedora 10.mail server is: sendmail.My mail server was running smoothly. But i re-configure my mail server /etc/mail/sendmail.mc file for make it more effective.But after the change made on mc file no mail is comming on any of my mail account from out side of the world but mail go to outside.Although no mail is going from my one mail account to anothermail account into the same lan.

Showing this error on sender end

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
   xyz@abc.com
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We
recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause
of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.7.1 
<xyz@abc.com>... Relaying denied (state 14).
```

When this problem happen then i just overwrite the previous mc file again.and do necessary m4 .But problem not solved yet .

.................................My previous sendmail.mc file........................

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
```

.....................................................................................

.............................Edited sendmail.mc file..................................

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`greet_pause',5000)
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `10')dnl
define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `250')dnl
define(`confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE', `1')dnl
define(`confMAX_RCPTS_PER_MESSAGE', `15')dnl
define(`confQUEUE_LA', `5')dnl
define(`confREFUSE_LA', `20')dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
```

........................................................................

Please guide me .What should i do now..

Thanks
with regards

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to answer your question, but please please please do yourself a massive favour and replace Sendmail with something easier to configure. Exim and Postfix are both good replacements. Exim is a little more flexible.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.I already solve the problem.Thanks GOD.

Comment: Can you answer your question with how you fixed it?

Comment: Exim may be flexible, but the configuration files can be a *nightmare* under Debian particularly. Some might liken the configuration to Perl ;) Write once, read never!  For ease of configuration and future maintainability, Postfix rocks.

Comment: /etc/mail/sendmail.cf file was not added 
Cwlocalhost
Cwxyz.com

Comment: Yes, Debian's default Exim config is a mess. Just stick a default one in /etc/exim4/exim4.conf and all the (Debian specific) pain goes away. I think we can all agree anything is less complicated to configure than sendmail.